# Sequences $(\lambda_n)$ such that for every summable sequence $(a_n)$, $(\lambda_na_n)$ is also summable.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

An oral examination exercise :

> Find all the sequences $(\lambda _n)_n$ of real numbers such that :
>   $$\sum a_n \; \text{is convergent} \Longrightarrow \sum \lambda_n a_n \; \text{is convergent}$$

I think the only working sequences are the ones which are bounded and ultimately of constant sign.

I've not seen it on the site so if you have seen it please tell me how you would solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is something to try with the abel transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Applications

Comment: @JohnMath take $a_n=1/n^2$ so that $\sum a_n$ converge but with $\lambda_n=n $ you get $\sum \lambda_na_n= \sum 1/n$ which diverge. So $\lambda_n=n$ is not a suitable sequence

Comment: you are right, sorry. my bad

Comment: Boundedness is not enough. If you take $a_n = (-1)^n / \sqrt{n}$, then the series converges. But, even if the sequence is of constant sign, you can slightly "bump up" the positive $a_n$, so that the series given by $\lambda_n a_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: @D.Thomine What was the $\lambda_n$ in your example?

Comment: @Dr.MV: you may take $\lambda_{2n} = 1$ and $\lambda_{2n+1} = 0$, but there are examples where $(\lambda_n)$ converges.

Comment: @D.Thomine you're right I said that $\lambda _n$ should be ultimately of constant sign for example $\lambda _n \geqslant 0$ for $n \geqslant N$. But if $\lambda_n$ is absolutely convergent there is no need.

Comment: @D.Thomine So, you classify $0$ as having positive sign?

Comment: @Dr.MV, well, take value 1 on even numbers and 1/2 on odd numbers.... You can tweak the example as you wish.

Comment: @D.Thomine Yes; that works! +1 for you comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequences of bounded variation, we must have

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lvert \lambda_{n+1} - \lambda_n\rvert < +\infty.$$

For a convergent series $\sum a_n$, consider the sequence of tail sums

$$r_n = \sum_{k = n}^\infty a_k.$$

Then $(r_n)$ is a sequence converging to $0$, and with $a_n = r_n - r_{n+1}$ a summation by parts yields

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^N \lambda_n a_n &= \sum_{n = 0}^N \lambda_n (r_n - r_{n+1})\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^N \lambda_n r_n - \sum_{n = 1}^{N+1} \lambda_{n-1} r_n\\
&= \lambda_0 r_0 - \lambda_N r_{N+1} + \sum_{n = 1}^N (\lambda_{n} - \lambda_{n-1}) r_n.
\end{align}

It is easy to see that the boundedness of $(\lambda_n)$ is necessary, so with that restriction we have $\lambda_N r_{N+1} \to 0$, and

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lambda_n a_n$$

is convergent if and only if

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\lambda_n - \lambda_{n-1})r_n\tag{1}$$

is convergent. Since $\sum \lambda_n a_n$ shall converge for *all* convergent $\sum a_n$, $(1)$ must converge for *all* $r \in c_0$, where $c_0$ is the Banach space of sequences converging to $0$, endowed with the supremum norm. The topological dual of $c_0$ is $\ell^1$, and by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, a sequence $(\mu_n)$ such that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N \mu_n\cdot r_n$$

exists for all $r\in c_0$ belongs to $\ell^1$.

Conversely, it is elementary to see that all sequences $(\lambda_n)$ of bounded variation have the desired property.

Comment: I don't know the Banach Steinhaus theorem neither the topological dual, can you be more precise or give reference please. In fact I just discovered the theorem and don't know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: Have you any background in functional analysis? It's going to be a lot to explain if not.

Comment: Just a little bit, I've seen the Baire's theorem. I understand the proof of Banach Steinhaus and I know what is a dual in linear algebra

Comment: Then we should be close to home. The topological dual, or continuous dual, of a topological vector space $X$ is the vector space of _continuous_ linear functionals on $X$. If you understand the proof of Banach-Steinhaus, you probably know and have understood that for a normed space $X$ we have the norm $\lVert \varphi\rVert = \sup \{ \lvert \varphi(x)\rvert : x\in X,\, \lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1\}$ on the topological dual. Is that all clear so far, or is there something new (beyond terminology) that needs further explanation?

Comment: This is clear I am friendly with operator norms

Comment: Hum.. I see what is your point, you used Banach Steinhaus for the continuity ! Clever !

Comment: Good. Next we have the identification between $\ell^1$ and $c_0'$ [or $c_0^{\ast}$, the notation for dual spaces is not uniform]. On the one hand, for $\xi \in \ell^1$ and $x\in c_0$, we know that $\sum \xi_n\cdot x_n$ converges absolutely, and thus $\varphi_{\xi} \colon x \mapsto \sum \xi_n \cdot x_n$ defines a linear functional on $c_0$. We have $$\lvert \varphi_{\xi}(x)\rvert \leqslant \sum \lvert \xi_n\rvert\cdot \lvert x_n\rvert \leqslant \sum \lvert\xi_n\rvert \cdot \lVert x\rVert_{c_0} = \lVert\xi\rVert_{\ell^1}\cdot \lvert x\rVert_{c_0},$$ so $\varphi_{\xi}$ is continuous with norm …

Comment: Can you give me a good reference for Banach analysis (I mean functional analysis and stuff like the duality) it would be so nice !

Comment: @M.LTA There are lots of good references around, but of course tastes differ, so what's good for one need not be good for all. I like Rudin's _Functional Analysis_, and _Introduction to Functional Analysis_ by Meise and Vogt is also a great book. But before spending a lot of money, I'd recommend going to the nearest university library and looking at the books on functional analysis they have. Spend some time looking whose style you like.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda_n$ is not bounded consider the sequence
$$a_n=\begin{cases}{}\sum_{j=p}^q\frac1{j^2}&\text{ if }\lambda_n<p\le q\le\lambda_{n+1}\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: in the future, use `\begin{array}{}...\end{array}` with the "extra" `{}` there.  Or, use the `\begin{cases}... \end{cases}` environment

Comment: Thank you. I could not remember the keywotd cases.